# using method of interface in golang from different file

Tags: go, struct, interface

I've `method` which I want to provide some interface to make it more easier to test

This is the function

**File A**

```
func readFile(s source) ([]byte, error) {
        p := fs.GetPath()
        file, err := ioutil.ReadFile(p + "/" + s.path + "/" + "rts.yaml")
        if err != nil {
            return yamlFile, fmt.Errorf("erro reading file : %s", err.Error())
        }
        return file, err
    }
```

Now I add for it struct

```
type source struct{
    path string
}
```

And the interface that the `readFile` is `implementing`

```
type fileReader interface {
    readFile(path string) ([]byte, error)
}
```

And now I need to call this function from another file but Im getting error while doing this

**File B**

```
type source struct {
    path string
}


a := source{}

yamlFile, err := readFile(a)
```

what am I missing here ?

Comment: What error?......

Comment: @zerkms  - the error is: "cannot use a as type source "

Comment: That's because `type source` in different packages are different non-assignable types

Comment: @zerkms - can you please provide example how to make it work correctly ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your intentions: your code is incomplete and you have not explained the original problem. One quick advice: you probably don't need to declare `source` type in both packages, but just in one. It's also not obvious how an interface could help with anything since you're not even using it.

Comment: @zerkms - my question is, assume that I've the `interface & func implementation and the struct`  in packageA/fileA and I want to use it in package B how should I do it ?

Comment: @zerkms - can you please provide example ?

Comment: Nothing in your code implements that interface https://tour.golang.org/methods/9

Comment: The func `readFile` is implementing the interface , why not ?

Comment: functions themselves do not implement interfaces, method receivers do

Comment: @NinaS does fileA and fileB belong to same package?

Comment: @zerkms - can be or not but lets start with the same package

Comment: @NinaS you cannot declare type with the same name twice in the same package

Comment: @zerkms - it will be great if you can take the `readFile` function  and put it as answer as it should be as implemented by interface . thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Import the package containing the `source` struct in `File A` and then use that struct to initialize the variable after that pass the variable to the `readFile` function.

**File B**

```
import A
a := A.Source{}
```

Because `source` struct in File A is different from `source` struct in File B. And `source` struct of File A is implementing the interface that's why you need to import the source struct and then pass it into the function.

One this should be noticed that to make any struct or function exportable you should start the struct or fucntion name with upper case letter.

**File A**

```
// make struct exportable
type Source struct{
    path string
}
```

implemented the interface which is different from

**File B**

```
type source struct{
    path string
}
```

which does not implemented the interface.

**Edited**

File A

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

type Source struct {
    Path string
}

type fileReader interface {
    readOneFile() ([]byte, error)
}

func(s Source) readOneFile() ([]byte, error) {
    cwd, err := os.Getwd()
    file, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fmt.Sprintf("%s/file.txt", cwd))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("erro reading file : %s", err.Error())
    }
    return file, err
}
```

File B

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    s := Source{}
    data, err := s.readOneFile()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("Error in reading the file")
    }
    fmt.Println(string(data))
}
```

Comment: Actually @NinaS assume to be both file in same package as written in their comments like `can be or not but lets start with the same package`

Comment: @saddam if they are in the same package then this error will not occur. Also, if the package is same you cannot create a struct with same name. It will panic before you run the program.

Comment: Thanks 1+ but how should I adopt the function/method ?  can you please update this https://play.golang.org/p/qg_jN3DyWN3

Comment: @NinaS ok let me implement on my system and get back to you.

Comment: Thank you for helping :)

Comment: Thanks I've checked it and its not working , one thing that it confusing is the `ReadFile` which is func and should be method , can you please change it to `readOneFile` and implement the interface and you will see that its not working...

Comment: @NinaS create a method receiver. I have updated the answer. Also it was working in my system. In case if it is not working please post the error too you are getting in your system.

Comment: Thank you :) last question , in case I want to add value to the `struct` should I do it like this  `s := Source{}
  s.path = myPath`

Comment: or there is a better way ?

Comment: or using the `New` keyword is better ?

Comment: @NinaS initialize the field when creating an instance of struct as s := Source{path:"filePath"}. Using new keyword will create a pointer to struct. For that you need to create pointer type receivers.

Comment: Thanks you very much I put it as answered :) , I've additional related question please see if you can help : )